# Case of "die Heimat" in "Expedition in die Heimat"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative, wechselpraeposition

I'm trying to identify and understand the case used in the phrase

> Expedition in die Heimat

My reasoning was that "in" being a wechselpräposition and there being no movement, the dative would be used, giving

> Expedition in *der* Heimat

but clearly I am wrong!

So which case is actually  being used here (and why!)?

Comment: The "movement/no movement" criterion is a really bad one. It's better to think about *location* (prep. + dat.) vs *direction toward s.th.* (prep. + acc.). Cf. the locative/allative cases in Indoeuropean languages.

Comment: *This is motion towards, isn't it, boy?* - *Dative? ... Ah! Not dative! Not the dative, sir! Ah! Ah! Oh! Accusative, accusative!* Sorry, could not resist ... :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence means "Expedition to the homestead" not "Expedition in the homestead". I'm not sure about the translation of "Heimat", though.

It's accusative, because there's motion *into* the homestead. With dative it would imply you're already in the place and roaming around.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I've always found translation of prepositions a bit tricky!